# Difference between setValues() and addValues()

Tags: magento2

In magento module for the back-end part, for admin form edit tab we are using

> addValues()

and

> setValues()

I want to know difference between those 2 functions

Comment: In simple term `setValues` reset the value and `addValue` append the value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find both function's definitions in file `vendor\magento\framework\Data\Form.php`.

> ```
> public function setValues($values)
> {
>     foreach ($this->_allElements as $element) {
>         if (isset($values[$element->getId()])) {
>             $element->setValue($values[$element->getId()]);
>         } else {
>             $element->setValue(null);
>         }
>     }
>     return $this;
> }
> ```

The `setValues($values)` function set values according to the array passed in it and set `null` for the keys which are not set.

Where `addValues($values)` function does the first part only means it only sets the keys which are available.

> ```
> public function addValues($values)
> {
>     if (!is_array($values)) {
>         return $this;
>     }
>     foreach ($values as $elementId => $value) {
>         $element = $this->getElement($elementId);
>         if ($element) {
>             $element->setValue($value);
>         }
>     }
>     return $this;
> }
> ```